# Why does ""Here strings" in bash changes the syntax color of whatever follows it?

Tags: bash, vim

I am writing a bash script which uses here strings (`<<<`), please see example below. The script works fine and gives expected output, but the problem is that the (vim) editor syntax color is all messed up after the line where here string was used. Any clues why and also how I can fix it ?

[image]

As text:

```sh
# get all running screens
scrcmd=$(ps auxw|grep -i screen|grep -v grep|awk '{print $15}')
allscr=()
while read -r line; do
        allscr+=("$line")
done <<< $scrcmd

echo "got screens, now do something else"
```

Comment: Please replace image by text or add text.

Comment: Presumably the syntax highlight rules don't know about here-docs, and treat them as here-strings.

Comment: What exactly are your syntax highlighting settings? At least include the output of `:set syntax` and `:set filetype`

Comment: If you had a proper shebang on your script (started it with `#!/bin/bash`), then vim should have configured itself properly.

Comment: Maybe my eyes are shot, but I can't even read what is on line 1. Also, perhaps I have old syntax files, but `$(` should be flagged as an error in the default `sh` highlighting without any other hints as to which shell to use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The bash (really `sh`) highlight mode in Vim is multipurpose; it tries to cover POSIX sh, bash, and ksh. You have to tell it you specifically want bash.

```
:let b:is_bash=1
:set ft=sh
```

It should highlight properly after that.

If you only ever care about bash, you could just make this your default in .vimrc:

```
let g:is_bash=1
```

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Charles Duffy in comments, if you use a `#!` line, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Then vim should do the right thing on its own. That is probably easier, unless you have some reason you prefer not use `#!` lines.

(Even though that's likely easier, I am leaving my answer here because in this case you do not have a `#!` line, and that is not uncommon, especially in library code or files expected to be sourced, not executed.)

Comment: There was also something like `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` Would it be possible to give vim hints in a similar manner for setting `is_bash=1`? I have some colleagues who don't want the files for sourcing to start with a shabang.

Comment: There are also cases where you have a non-bash `#!`, but you want proper bash highlighting. For instance https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core

Comment: How can this setting be included in a "vim embedded config" near the start or end of a specific file? E.g. "# vim: g:is_bash=1 ft=sh" gives a vim error on file open...

Comment: "vim modeline" is what it's called - cannot edit comments after 5 minutes, just found this out after a few searches... still want to know how to embed this 'setting' in a vim modeline..

Comment: @zenaan I'd suggest you post that as a new question with the [vim] tag so other vim experts will see it (they won't see it here in a comment)

Comment: Just found a plugin: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=83  - it's not in the Debian vim-scripts package, but easy to add to local .vim/autoload :)

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks a lot. Saved a trip to the inner settings of vim bash highlight!

Comment: Thanks ! Looking for that for a long time